# Cypress .replace() method

Tags: cypress

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muuwg.png)
I want to put found text in a list then .log() it

I copied the .replace() method from my previous code but I only know how to make it put a space after 5 letters. Is there a way to make it separate each "word" from a different div's? My log looks like this [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CTTz.png)  and I want it to look like:
isSystemObject name description avatar tags isSystemObject name description avatar tags

Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `each()` method to loop over all elements, extract the text and then apply the `replace()` method like this:

```js
cy.get('#header').find('#label').each(($ele) => {
  const nazwy = $ele.text().trim().replace(/(.{5})/g,"$1 ")
  cy.log(nazwy)//prints label texts one by one
})
```